# executing ContinueWith when other continuations have not executed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, continuations

Given something like this:

```
.ContinueWith((_, o) => this.Foo(), null, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
.ContinueWith((_, o) => this.Bar(), null, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
.ContinueWith((_, o) => this.AnythingElse(), null, TaskContinuationOptions.?
```

Is there any way to construct a continuation that will execute `AnythingElse` when the other continuations have not executed?

I want to catch all other possible terminations, but only if one of the first two continuations above have not executed already.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to execute `AnythingElse`only if Foo or Bar didn't finish yet ? It's not very clear to me because you use `ContinueWith` (which means: run _this_ after the previous task completed), but you say you want to continue only if they haven't executed already

Comment: I want anythingelse to execute if there was no exception and it didn't run to completion - more importantly - under any circumstances that foo and bar were not executed.

Comment: _I want anythingelse to execute if there was no exception and it didn't run to completion_ how can it not run to completion ? do you want to set a timeout ? I'm not exactly sure what you mean here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OnlyOnCancelled` because that is the only other case.

You also can use one unified continuation and decide what to do based on task status. I think that's the cleanest way because it results in sequential looking code.

Comment: I'm afraid just using `OnlyOnCanceled` on the current piece of code will not work in case it's `Foo` who gets canceled.

Comment: If Foo is cancelled neither the antecedent (not shown here) nor the ContinueWith task will end up in a cancelled state.